# Solve $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=-r(x(t)-x_e)+d(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given is the following ODE:

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-r(x(t)-x_e)+d(t).$$

where (d,t) are time functions. Any ideas how to find $x(t)$? What confuses me is that both $x$ and $d$ are two dependent variables on $t$.

Is this just a substitution problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry, $r$ and $x_e$ are both constants

Comment: $d(t)$ is unknown

Comment: Isn't $dt$ just the differential and $d(t)$ a function? I guess it's just the notation causing trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the ODE

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=-r(x(t)-x_e)+d(t) \tag 1$$

Rearranging $(1)$, we obtain

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+rx(t)=d(t)+rx_e \tag 2$$

whereupon multiplying both sides by $e^{rt}$ yields

$$\frac{d(e^{rt}x(t))}{dt}=e^{rt}\left(d(t)+rx_e\right) \tag 3$$

Next, we integrate both sides of $(3)$ from $t_0$ to $t_f$ and find

$$x(t_f)=x_e+e^{-r(t_f-t_0)}(x(t_0)-x_e)+\int_{t_0}^{t_f} d(t)e^{-r(t_f-t)}\,dt$$

---

If we take the indefinite integral on both sides of $(3)$ we obtain

$$x(t)=x_e+\int^t d(t')e^{-r(t-t')}\,dt'+Ce^{-rt}$$

Comment: Thank you for you answer, could you explain in greater depth how you derived (3) from (2)?

Comment: You're welcome Luke!  My pleasure.  Carryout the derivative on the left-hand side of $(3)$ and divide both sides by $e^{rt}$.  See the result.  The approach falls under the broader umbrella of finding an integrating factor.  Any linear first-order ODE can be solved using this methodology.

Comment: Sorry Mark, I am still struggling to understand how you managed to jump from (2) to (3). How did you integrate both sides and put the result in terms of x?

Comment: Luke, to go from $(2)$ to $(3)$, multiply both sides of $(2)$ by $e^{rt}$, then recognize that the left-hand side is the result of the derivative of the product $e^{rt}x(t)$.  Then integrate both sides of $(3)$ with respect to $t$ from $t_0$ to $t_f$.

Comment: Can't you just leave it as an indefinite integral?

Comment: Yes, we could certainly do that.  But then we need to add an arbitrary integration constant.

Comment: Could you provide your answer for when the integral is indefinite so that I can compare my result?

Comment: I get the following $\ x = x_e+e^{-rt}\int d(t)e^{rt}dt+ce^{-rt}$ is this right or did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: Luke, that is precisely the answer I reported in the revised solution. Well done!  -Mark

Comment: You're welcome Luke.  My pleasure.

Comment: Mark can you explain how my integral is the same as yours in the answer? $e^{-rt}$ is not inside of the integral in my solution

Comment: Ahhhhh, never mind, I figured it out :P

Comment: Luke, I added an upper limit on the indefinite integral to clarify.  Apology for the omission